# How to make changes to .list files permanent?

Tags: apt

On an `apt-get update` I got the common error:

> W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Per the answers on other questions, I changed the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list` file to include the `[arch=amd64]` part to it. However, as the file itself warns,

> THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED
>
> You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.

so that I have to change it every now and then.

How can I make that change permanent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question :).  I had a related problem on Fedora, so I did the equivalent of renaming `google-earth.list` to `my-google-earth.list` (or maybe `google-earth-amd64.list`) before editing it.

From Google's point of view, the user had deleted `google-earth.list`, and they avoid recreating it.  In case you wanted to disable updates, I guess.

You might prefer to leave `google-earth.list` in place instead, but comment out the line, and then create a copy `my-google-earth.list` which has your own version of the line.

Both approaches could be a bit confusing.  I think my approach felt less confusing to me, because I'd written script (an Ansible role) where I could save a comment why I was doing this.

---

```
# If we create google-chrome.repo ourself, the package wants to reset baseurl.
# Whereas if google-chrome.repo does not exist, it is considered to be deleted
# or otherwise disabled by user action.  It will not be recreated.  So we can
# set up our own local-google-chrome.repo.
```

Comment: But where is the original .list file configured from? Which process does that?

Comment: /etc/cron.daily/google-chrome